# HTTP GET no JAVA com resultado diferente do POSTMAN

Tags: java, json, api, rest, gson

Estou realizando um HTTP Get Request no Java utilizando o Gson para utilização dos dados no meu programa, porém o primeiro e o último atributo estão vindo como nulos. Porém, ao realizar a requisição no POSTMAN vi que realmente o resultado está errado.

Segue meu código de requisição no JAVA e as respostas:

```
try{
            String url = "https://api.codenation.dev/v1/challenge/dev-ps/generate-data?token=MEUTOKEN";

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                System.out.println("Erro " + conn.getResponseCode() + " ao obter dados da URL " + url);
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);

            }
            br.close();
            conn.disconnect();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Mensagem mensagem = gson.fromJson(response.toString(),Mensagem.class);

            System.out.println("CASAS: "+ mensagem.getNum_casas());
            System.out.println("TOKEN: " + mensagem.getToken());
            System.out.println("CIFRADO: "+ mensagem.getCifrado());
            System.out.println("DESCIFRADO: "+ mensagem.getDecifrado());
            System.out.println("Resumo: "+ mensagem.getResumo_criptográfico());

        }catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Classe Mensagem

```
public class Mensagem {

    private String num_casas;
    private String token;
    private String cifrado;
    private String decifrado;
    private String resumo_criptográfico;

    public Mensagem(String num_casas, String token, String cifrado, String decifrado, String resumo_criptográfico) {
        this.num_casas = num_casas;
        this.token = token;
        this.cifrado = cifrado;
        this.decifrado = decifrado;
        this.resumo_criptográfico = resumo_criptográfico;
    }

    public String getNum_casas() {
        return num_casas;
    }

    public void setNum_casas(String num_casas) {
        this.num_casas = num_casas;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getCifrado() {
        return cifrado;
    }

    public void setCifrado(String cifrado) {
        this.cifrado = cifrado;
    }

    public String getDecifrado() {
        return decifrado;
    }

    public void setDecifrado(String decifrado) {
        this.decifrado = decifrado;
    }

    public String getResumo_criptográfico() {
        return resumo_criptográfico;
    }

    public void setResumo_criptográfico(String resumo_criptográfico) {
        this.resumo_criptográfico = resumo_criptográfico;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mensagem{" +
                "num_casas=" + num_casas +
                ", token='" + token + '\'' +
                ", cifrado='" + cifrado + '\'' +
                ", decifrado='" + decifrado + '\'' +
                ", resumo_criptográfico='" + resumo_criptográfico + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
CASAS: null
TOKEN: MEU TOKEN
CIFRADO: ahsr pz jolhw, zovd tl aol jvkl! spubz avychskz
DESCIFRADO: 
Resumo: null
```

Porém quando realizado a requisição no POSTMAN, o resultado é:

```
{
    "numero_casas": 7,
    "token": "MEUTOKEN",
    "cifrado": "ahsr pz jolhw, zovd tl aol jvkl! spubz avychskz",
    "decifrado": "",
    "resumo_criptografico": ""
}
```

Alguém conseguiria me ajudar a descobrir **pq a primeira e última linha estão saindo como null ?** Acredito que seja algum detalhe com o BufferedReader na qual não me atentei.

Comment: Coloque o código da classe `Mensagem`.

Comment: Atualizei com a classe Mensagem

Comment: Veja no [**tour**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) como agradecer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome do campo na classe Mensagem não bate com o nome do campo no JSON.

num_casas vs. numero_casas

O mesmo para o outro campo que está vindo nulo, o problema é o acento.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo!